# All observations for some variables is zero, which regression model to use?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have an assignment to create a regression model using leave-one-out cross validation.

Due to specific biological nature, the variables cannot be negatively correlated to the response variable.

There are 12 variables and 66 observations in total. 1 of the variable had observations that are either numeric or zero, while another 2 variables were zeros for all observations. The remaining 9 variables were numeric.

I have ran the following and ended up with a warning that says "In predict.lm(modelFit, newdata) : prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading".

```
set.seed(2)

install.packages('caret')

library(caret)


#Define training control
train.control <- trainControl(method = 'LOOCV')

#Train the model
train.model <- train(Y ~., data = OSbiome, method = 'lm', trControl = train.control)
summary(train.model)
print(train.model)
warnings()
```

Not sure if the warning received was due to the fact that 2 of the variables were zero for all observations? Any suggestions on what model to use then? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the variables that are always 0 in your dataset are a problem - there's no way to estimate the associated parameters.  I would omit those variables from the model entirely; you can list the remaining variables explicitly inside `train()`, or remove them from `OSbiome`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the input! Yes I tried removing those variables and I obtained a multiple R-squared value of 0.05723 and a p-value of 0.968, which indicate that the model is poorly fitted. Though I think linear regression is most suited for the scenario because the response variable is numerical (between 0.2 and 1).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.